Modulus of a function in $H^2_0(\Omega)$ is also in $H^2_0(\Omega)$?
It is well known that for a bounded domain $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and for a function $u \in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ it is true that $|u| \in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$. I would like to know it the same happens to $v \in W^{2,2}_0(\Omega)$. To prove this, I know it is enough to prove that $u^+, u^- \in W^{2,2}_0(\Omega)$, but I don't know how to do this. If this is true, is there a good reference with this fact?

Try a simple example like $u(x) = x$

To further embark on @fwd 's comment: The weak derivative of $\lvert x \rvert$ is $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$. You know that this has a classical derivative a.e., so you know a candidate for the weak derivative on that subset. Try to take this to a contradiction
